# How to read a cookie in chrome extension to make sure user is logged in on my website

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a user who will log in to my website using credentials (Not google Oauth). Once he is logged in, I want to check if he is logged in on my website using the chrome extension.

**Manifest.json**

```
"host_permissions": [
  "*://*.mydomain.com/"
],
"permissions": [
  "storage",
  "cookies"
],
```

**background.js**

```
function getCookies(domain, name, callback) {
    chrome.cookies.get({"url": domain, "name": name}, function(cookie) {
        if(callback) {
            callback(cookie.value);
        }
    });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {

    getCookies("mydomain.com", "my_cookie_name", function (cookie_value) {
        chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(cookie_value)
    });

})
```

**Content Script**

This sends messages to background.js

```
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({text, style, platform, isBig: Boolean(element)}, function (response) {
            updateInput(response, element);
           
        })
```

I don't see any log output here. Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Who sendMessage to background.js?

Comment: Remove `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().` and use [devtools for background.js console](/a/10258029).

Comment: @NorioYamamoto  Updated by question. Content script sends a message.